# Changing menuitem on returning from activity

Tags: java, android

I want to change the menuitem register of my menu when I return from another activity to settings which will go to a new intent. On clicking register which is in menu_item the activity goes to RegisterActivity. On returning from RegisterActivity I want to change the menu item register to settings.

```
package com.mausamakasvani.srsk.mausamakasvani;


public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText password;
    private EditText userName;
    public static boolean Register;
    public static final int REG_REQ_CODE = 235;
    private int x = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        ActionBar as = getSupportActionBar();
        as.setTitle("Login");
        userName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
        password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
    }
    public void onLoginClicked(View view){
        /*
        */
        if (!MausamCheckList.getStringValue(this,MausamCheckList.USER_NAME).equals(MausamCheckList.DEF_VALUE)) {
            if (userName.getText().toString().equals(MausamCheckList.getStringValue(this, MausamCheckList.USER_NAME)) && password.getText().toString().equals(MausamCheckList.getStringValue(this, MausamCheckList.PASSWORD))) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this,SheharChunoActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                //finish();
            }else {
                MausamCheckList.displayToast(this,"Username or Password is Wrong!!!");
            }
        }else{
            MausamCheckList.displayToast(this,"Please register");
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
           if(x==0)
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_login, menu);

        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,RegisterActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent,REG_REQ_CODE);
                        //startActivity(intent);
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REG_REQ_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RegisterActivity.REG_RES_CODE) {
                x=RegisterActivity.REG_RES_CODE;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include both menu items in one menu.xml file and depending on what you want to show change visibility of particular item. You can simple hold reference to `Menu` (and use `findItem` method as well) or `MenuItem` inside your activity and manage it like this (pseudo-code):

```
if(user.isRegistered()) {
   mSettingsMenuItem.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   mRegisterMenuItem.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

You can also use

```
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu (Menu menu)
```

which is called everytime menu is shown on the screen and depending on the conditions show proper menu items

[Documentation for this](http://developer.android.com/intl/vi/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29)